# is there a way to create After update triggers or Events in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i want to know if there is way to create something like an After insert trigger or an asynchronous event that looks regularly through a log table and then apply the changes to another database.

i found something about the use of middlewares or the use of vanilla js functions but because of the different nommenclatures or perhaps the unclear documentation i don't think that's going to work for me.
if anyone could clarify the use of post hooks on update or a promise in a function that would be great.

Basically what i want is a trigger or an event that listens to an order details table, i have 2 types of orders: current and delivered in the first type a field called deliveryDate is empty when it's updated and a value is entered in the field it should capture it and insert it in another Database.

i have a function called update that is executed everytime the route `'/myApp'` gets a `POST` request here is an example not far from what i want to do 
here is the route:

```
 module.exports = (app) => {
 const Something= require('../controllers/something.controller.js')
 // Create a new something
 app.post('/Myapp', Something.update);}
```

here is the controller:

```
const Something = require('../models/something.model.js');
const SomethingLog = require('../models/something.log.model.js');
exports.update = (req, res) => {//function body}
```

can i create a post hook under the `exports.update` function like putting the hook in a function and if i do so how will i be able to execute it should i a just assign it to the default post route wouldn't that conflict with the existing route? thank you

Comment: Use Mongoose middleware: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: read the question i read the docs but they weren't clear nor exhaustive of most use cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mongoose middlewares](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) for this

There are two types in middleware:

1. Pre

before the operation is carried out

```
schema.pre('update', function(next) {

    // do something

    next();   //dont forget next();

});
```

2. Post

after the operation is carried out

```
schema.post('update', function(next) {

    // do something

    next();   //dont forget next();

});
```

> Note:
>
> you will need to write this middleware in your **collection** file on which you want this operations to be carried out.
>
> Second, "update" is the operation done on your collection, in case of "pre" middleware will execute before the update on collection and when middleware calls next() it proceeds with the update operation and in case of "post" middleware is executed after the update operation

Comment: and what are 'update' and next representing here excuse if i sound a little bit repetitive but i want to get a thorough understanding of this

Comment: 'update' is the operation being performed on your collection. And if you define a middleware on the update operation, this middleware will get called.

Comment: There are other operations supported to like "save", "remove", "deleteOne", "fineOneAndUpdate" etc, read docs.

Comment: "next" is supposed to be called when things you want to do in middleware are over, and you want to pass the control to next operation.

Comment: Like in pre middleware on "update", the update won't happen if next is not called in middleware.

Comment: when you perform db.your_collection.update(....) operation, as we have middleware on the "update", this middleware will be called.

Comment: but i have a function called update that is executed everytime the route `'/myApp'` gets a `POST` request here is an example not far from what i want to do 
here is the route:
`module.exports = (app) => {
    const Something= require('../controllers/something.controller.js');

    // Create a new something
    app.post('/Myapp', something.update);}`
here is the controller:
`const Something = require('../models/something.model.js');
const SomethingLog = require('../models/something.log.model.js');
exports.update = (req, res) => {//function body}`

Comment: can i create my hook under the `exports.update` function like putting the hook in a function and if i do so how will i be able to execute it should i a just assign it to the default post route? thank you

Comment: Okay i understand a little bit what you were explaining for example if i have this in my model file 

`const ConsumableSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    reference: String,
    description: String,
    quantity: Number,
    approv : Number,
    price: Number,
    unit: String

});
`
i should do something like `ConsumableSchema.pre('update' function(){})`
in the same file if i understand this correctly

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755806/mongoose-middleware-post-update-not-working) You can add a hook on after updation like this:

```
schema.post("update", function(doc) {
  console.log('Updated');
});
```

Comment: okay so `"update"` is the update function i created or something built-in if it's the one i created that would be formidable

Comment: Update is predefined